# Downloaded font that has differet font styles

Tags: file, fonts, styles

I downloaded a font.  It has 4 separate styles, how can I choose one over the other to use.  They are listed separately in one file in my font folder.  But when I look at my list of fonts to use only one shows up

Comment: The particular font in question is Callie-Mae

Comment: It seems to me that they are 4 separate fonts. So you should reference them by their full name: `Callie-Mae Bold` or `Callie-Mae Normal`

Answer (score 0):

Each style should have a number, for example, a regular font would be 400, semibold 600, and bold 700. It depends on the font you are using.

To specify which style, you should specify the `font-family` and the `font-weight` which is one of the above mentioned numbers.

For example:

```
font-family: Callie-Mae, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
```

Comment: i don't know if 400 is the weight of the regular style of the font you are using, but i have written it 400 as an example, so it might differ in your case.